# How to get the method body of an Anonymous methods in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'm trying to implement something similar to Hangfire, where a background task does some of the more time-consuming work, but with the difference that the task is generated on multiple lightweight servers and then processed by one or more dedicated servers via a queue.

I want to implement the following method.

```
public void GetMethodInfo<T>(Func<T> value)
```

I want to find the calling procedure inside the anonymous method.

Eg

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ClassA a = new ClassA();

    GetMethodInfo(()=>{ return a.GetXXXTableList(); })
    int pageIndex=1;
    int pageSize=10;
    int pageCount;
    GetMethodInfo(()=>{ return a.GetYYYTableList(pageIndex,pageSize,out pageCount); })
}

static void GetMethodInfo<T>(Func<T> value)
{
    //I want to get the internally called a.GetTableList or a.GetYYYTableList method through value
}

class ClassA
{
    public List<XXXDTO> GetXXXTableList()
    {
        List<XXXDTO> list = new List<XXXDTO>()//do anything
        //Do some other operations after querying data from the database
        return list;
    }
    public List<YYYDTO> GetYYYTableList(int pageIndex,int pageSize,out int pageCount)
    {
        pageCount = 0;
        List<YYYDTO> list = new List<YYYDTO>()//do anything
        //Do some other operations after querying data from the database
        return list;
    }
}
```

The reason is that some methods take a long time to run and do not require high real-time performance.

I want to get the methods that are actually called internally through the anonymous method passed in. Only one method will be called inside the anonymous function. Because the parameters for different methods are slightly different, creating multiple delegates is the worst option.

Here is the way I tried.

```
static void GetMethodInfo<T>(Func<T> value)
{

    StackFrame[] infm = null;
    value += () => { infm = new StackTrace().GetFrames(); T val = default; return val; };

    var name = value.Method.Name;

    var dataargs = value.GetType().GetGenericArguments();

    var dgls = value.GetInvocationList();
    var mti = value.GetMethodInfo();

    var methodResult = value.Invoke();

    StackFrame[] fms = new StackTrace().GetFrames();
    var fms1 = fms[fms.Length - 1].GetMethod().Name;

    Debugger.Break();
}
```

all of them don't work.

```
//The information obtained is all 
<GetMethod1>b__0
```

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.
Thanks in advance.

English is not my native language; please excuse typing errors.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. I'm afraid your question is not very clear. Please read [ask]. It seems like you are skipping a few steps in your explanation, and asking us to solve some complex technical issues you are having with your solution to the underlying problem. There probably is a much easier solution of spawning background tasks. Note: a database context does not support concurrency. So please give a good description of the actual underlying problem

Comment: Looks like you are trying to reinvent something like Hangfire. You can use expression trees for this but in general you should not do this, because serializing and deserializing expression trees can have quite some caveats (like code and libraries versions).

Answer (score -3):

In C#, anonymous methods don't have a direct way to retrieve their method bodies like named methods. However, you can achieve this using a combination of techniques involving delegates, reflection, and lambda expressions. Here's how you can do it:

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Reflection;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Define an anonymous method
        Action<int> anonymousMethod = delegate(int x)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Anonymous method called with {x}");
        };

        // Get the delegate's MethodInfo
        MethodInfo methodInfo = anonymousMethod.Method;

        // Use reflection to get the IL instructions
        byte[] ilBytes = methodInfo.GetMethodBody().GetILAsByteArray();

        // Create a LambdaExpression from IL instructions
        LambdaExpression lambda = Expression.Lambda(Expression.GetFuncType(), ilBytes);

        // Compile and execute the lambda
        Delegate compiledDelegate = lambda.Compile();
        compiledDelegate.DynamicInvoke();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

n this example, an anonymous method is defined using a delegate. The GetMethodBody() method of the delegate's MethodInfo is used to get the IL instructions of the anonymous method. Then, these IL instructions are wrapped in a LambdaExpression and compiled into a delegate, which can be invoked to execute the anonymous method's body.

Comment: This answer looks like ChatGPT